# Perl copy command to wait till copying completes

Tags: perl, copy

I copy a file from location windowsLocation1 to LinuxLocation1 as "windowsLocation1->windowsLocation2-> LinuxLocation1", windowsLocation2 being the swap area accessible from both windows and Linux machine

```
copy("//server1/dir1/myfile.txt", "$copy_dir/myfile.txt") or die "Copy failed: $!";
<telnet into Linux machine>
$obj->{telnet}->print( "sleep 10; cp /net/dir1/myfile.txt /tmp/files/");
#added "sleep 10, to avoid the race condition between copy and cp.
```

This "sleep 10" seconds is not sufficient sometimes, and its throwing error as "cp: read error: Input/output error", I think the second "cp" command is trying to access the file when first "copy" command is still writing. using Perl v5.6.1

Is there a way to avoid this? thanks.

Comment: Can this be refactored to use a robust protocol such as `scp`?

Comment: Hi Jim, scp not supported in my version of Perl, it will take some time to migrate all our scripts to latest Perl. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you're getting your `copy` routine from the `File::Copy` module.

After a brief search on CPAN I've discovered a module named [`File::Copy::Vigilant`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Copy::Vigilant) that seems like it might suit your needs, and has successful test reports from perl 5.6.

I've also found [`File::Copy::Reliable`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Copy::Reliable) but that only has reports back as far as perl 5.8, though that is proof of nothing.  You may just be a bit of a time traveling pioneer as far as this module is concerned....

Comment: @Krish Any chance we get to know which module you chose to go with?